# Images are not showing up on IE8 - Related to width property?

Tags: css, asp.net, image, internet-explorer-8

I am working on GunsAmerica.com and some users with IE8 are noticing (with great distaste) that the images are not showing up on our listings. I am using Browserstack.com to test and can confirm the beheavior. You can see the problem on the homepage http://www.gunsamerica.com

Here is the CSS for the image:

```
    .listing-thumb img, .listing-thumb > a > img {
      height:auto;
      width: 170px;
      display:inline;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
```

Here is an example listing image html:

```
<div class="listing-thumb">
            <a href="/945864089/CSC_ARMS_Elite_Model_2014_5_56_223_1.htm" alt="CSC ARMS " elite="" model"="" 2014="" 5.56="" .223="" 16""="" title="CSC ARMS " class="sr_image"><img itemprop="image" alt="CSC ARMS " elite="" model"="" 2014="" 5.56="" .223="" 16""="" src="/UserImages/142343/945864089/wm_md_6737932.jpg"></a><br>

        </div>
```

The class "sr_image" doesn't do anything so try to ignore that.

As far as I can tell it should work. Anyone that can help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What browser mode and document mode is the page using by default when accessed with IE8? (Bring up F14 developer tools to see)

Comment: Compatiblity view actually makes the images come up.. but breaks way more crap on the design than it's worth. Here is the meta:

Comment: Oops here ya go

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

Comment: Pierce, It would be helpful to know what browser mode and document mode are being selected by IE, as it can differ from what you specify in the HTML.

Comment: Hey Mason, sorry about the confusion - Browser Mode: IE8
Document Mode: IE Standards

Comment: I looked at your HTML. You have a lot of weird double quotes. Valid HTML is `attribute="value"`, not `attribute"="value"`. If you want double quotes in the value you need to escape them in order to have valid HTML. Have you run the HTML through the [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/)? It would point out a lot of those problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys it's working now. What seemed to be the issue was **the width property of the div that was enclosing it** with the class "listing_thumb". This apparently required a width to be set because the inner  wasn't giving the container width information (required static px width).

**From:**

```
.listing-thumb {
margin: 0px 10px;
display: inline;
float: left;
max-height: 119px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

**To:**

```
.listing-thumb {
margin: 0px 10px;
display: inline;
float: left;
max-height: 119px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 170px;
}
```

So there ya have it folks. If you've exhausted all other possibilities make sure all the enclosing containers have width properties that support the inner html.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
    a img { display: inline; }
</style>   
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... this still isn't working :\

Answer (score 0):

The solution about making the website compatible with IE8 will be temporary, because Microsoft is going to get rid of it anyway.

Check the link below for information on how to resolve the problem:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/310368/Make-Site-Compatible-to-IE-IE-IE-and-IE

Comment: Although Microsoft may discontinue support for IE8, that doesn't mean all users will upgrade. In fact, for the target audience of that site it's actually highly likely that they'll still use unsupported versions of IE. So just hoping the problem goes away isn't a valid solution.

Comment: I am aware that it is temporary, and I hope they kill it soon! In the mean time there are 80k users / month that use the site with IE 8 so I will still need to help them out.

Comment: Also I am looking through the codeproject for a solution... Unfortunately I've extinguished many of the suggestions already. If anyone has any insight it would be extremely helpful